# Counting record values in Oracle

Tags: oracle

First of all please accept my apologize because of bad english. Also I'm new to this portal. I hope you'll help me for my questions.

I have two questions in Oracle.

1. How to find the number of '*' in each column on the table.
2. how to find the total number of '*' in the table.

- The first question answer will be 2 2 3
- The second one answer will be 7.

Thanks in advance to spend your valuable time to answer my questions!

```
C1  C2  C3
*   1   1
0   0   *
1   *   *
*   *   *
```

Comment: How is the answer to first is 2 3 4, there are 2 2 and 3 stars in c1, c2, c3 columns respectively?

Comment: I'm so sorry and thanks for letting me know. Now I changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select sum(
case when c1='*' then 1
else 0 end) c1_cnt,
sum(
case when c2='*' then 1
else 0 end) c2_cnt,
sum(
case when c3='*' then 1
else 0 end) c3_cnt,
sum(
regexp_count(c1||c2||c3,'\*')) cnt_total_stars
from cnt_star;
```

| C1_CNT | C2_CNT | C3_CNT | CNT_TOTAL_STARS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 7 |

For the original table -

```
select * from cnt_star;
```

| C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| * | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | * |
| 1 | * | * |
| * | * | * |

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation to count the stars in each column and for the total stars just add the previous totals:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(CASE c1 WHEN '*' THEN 1 END) AS c1_stars,
       COUNT(CASE c2 WHEN '*' THEN 1 END) AS c2_stars,
       COUNT(CASE c3 WHEN '*' THEN 1 END) AS c3_stars,
       COUNT(CASE c1 WHEN '*' THEN 1 END)
       + COUNT(CASE c2 WHEN '*' THEN 1 END)
       + COUNT(CASE c3 WHEN '*' THEN 1 END) AS total_stars
FROM   table_name
```